# cookie based login system in android

Tags: java, php, android, session-cookies, httpurlconnection

i am trying to create an android app for some website. First I need to create a login system on this app that will ask user for its username and password and then send this data to some php script on server which will check in database weather this user exist in it or not. And thus returns user id. Following is my core code for this process

```
myurl="http://10.0.2.2:80/login.php?username=name&pass=password"
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
```

This part is working properly. I am able to get correct response from this. Now what I need is to maintain this session via cookies or any other method even if user closes this application so as to keep user logged in until and unless he logs out manually.
my login.php is somewhat as follow

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$userid = checkLogin($name, $pass);

if($userid!=NULL) {
    echo $userid;
} else { 
    echo "";
}
?>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: You might want to use $_POST since the "signed in" status could be considered a change in the state of the server.  I'm not sure about that -- it would depend on your app design.

Comment: If you plan to use this in production, you should change your authentication server so that only your own client can send information to it, otherwise you'll be subject to brute force attempts at finding passwords. You should also send the information over SSL or somehow else encrypt the username and password sent over the wire. I would look into libraries that already provide authentication instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using PHP session_start(), placing data in the session and modifying it?  This script will help you make the test.  If that works, you can almost certainly use PHP setcookie() to preserve client state.

```
<?php // RAY_session_test.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// DEMONSTRATE HOW PHP SESSIONS WORK
// MAN PAGE HERE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php


// START THE SESSION (DO THIS FIRST, UNCONDITIONALLY, IN EVERY PHP SCRIPT ON EVERY PAGE)
session_start();

// INITIALIZE THE SESSION ARRAY TO SET A DEFAULT VALUE
if (empty($_SESSION["cheese"])) $_SESSION["cheese"] = 1;

// SEE IF THE CORRECT SUBMIT BUTTON WAS CLICKED
if (isset($_POST['fred']))
{
    // ADD ONE TO THE CHEESE
    $_SESSION['cheese']++;
}

// RECOVER THE CURRENT VALUE FROM THE SESSION ARRAY
$cheese = $_SESSION['cheese'];


// END OF PROCESSING SCRIPT - CREATE THE FORM USING HEREDOC NOTATION
$form = <<<ENDFORM
<html>
<head>
<title>Session Test</title>
</head>
<body>
Currently, SESSION["cheese"] contains: $cheese<br/>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="increment this cheese" name="fred"  />
<input type="submit" value="leave my cheese alone" name="john" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
ENDFORM;

echo $form;
```

Comment: but this will all be on server...right?
i want to maintain cookie on client side

Comment: PHP sessions use cookies to find the server-side data.  So this is a very easy way to see if the device is acting like a well-behaved browser, accepting and returning the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

you should use HttpContext when executing your request and then the session cookie will be handled  within httpcontext. Each time you execute the hhtpRequest you must pass the httpcontext.

This is the mecanism to maintain the session.

Comment: Personnally I don't use android's http framework but directly the last version of the http client from Apache. So my code is litle complicated for your case

Comment: can you please elaborate more on how to use httpcontext to handle cookies??

Comment: use the following librarie http://loopj.com/android-async-http/   you can find enough help infos